# SharePoint Search not working with datetime

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, date-time

I have configured a search on SharePoint 2010 and i got all results as expected from each field. But when i search using date (`5/19/2015`), i don't get results from site.

I have already make field searchable from managed properties.

Comment: did you run the crawl after making that changes

Comment: yes i have run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to search on date values from SharePoint fields you must set up a managed property that maps the crawled property of your SharePoint field, then do a full crawl. After that type in the managed property name : value. `For example datefield:12/31/2009.`

[Check this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/9a30a176-8e9f-4152-95a0-3626316960c1/sharepoint-2010-date-columns-are-not-indexing-or-searchable)

[Manage metadata properties for search (Search Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164182.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: not working with managed property